# Service check with api in Icinga2

Tags: monitoring

I am trying to do add service of client using icinga2 api. I have followed https://github.com/saurabh-hirani/icinga2-api-examples. Here is what I have done so far.

First I created zone and endpoint in master as follows:

**Endpoint**

```
Object Endpoint "client.com" {
}
```

**Zone**

```
Object Zone "client.com" {
    endpoints = [ "client.com" ]
    parent = "master.com"
}
```

Restarted icinga2

Then in client server

```
#!/bin/bash -e

. icinga2_vars


echo "CREATING HOSTGROUP"


curl -s -u $ICINGA2_API_USER:$ICINGA2_API_PASSWORD \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT \
    -k "https://$ICINGA2_HOST:$ICINGA2_API_PORT/v1/objects/hostgroups/client_hostgroup" \
    -d '{ "attrs": {
            "display_name": "client host group"
} }' | python -m json.tool


echo "CREATING HOST"


curl -s -u $ICINGA2_API_USER:$ICINGA2_API_PASSWORD  \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT \
    -k "https://$ICINGA2_HOST:$ICINGA2_API_PORT/v1/objects/hosts/client.com" \
    -d '{ "templates": [ "generic-host" ],
        "attrs": {
        "address": "127.0.0.1",
        "check_command": "hostalive",
        "groups": ["client_hostgroup"],
        "vars.notification['mail']": {
            "groups": ["client_hostgroup_users"]
            }
} }' | python -m json.tool

echo "CREATING SERVICE"


curl -s -u $ICINGA2_API_USER:$ICINGA2_API_PASSWORD  \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT \
    -k "https://$ICINGA2_HOST:$ICINGA2_API_PORT/v1/objects/services/client.com!load" \
    -d '{
        "templates": [ "generic-service" ],
        "attrs": {
            "display_name": "check load",
            "check_command" : "load",
            "command_endpoint": "client.com",
            "host_name": "client.com"
        }
}' | python -m json.tool
```

It is working but checking service of master itself. It should check service of client server.

Comment: Let me know if anyone have better approach with nrpe so that we do not have to touch master server. all commands will be send to client server from master.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the correct zone attribute for the host and the service, so they will propagate to the client node.

Add `"zone": "client.com"` to the api requests.